# Managing C software configurations at compile time

Tags: c, gcc

I have developed a small library called dataframe that takes in a buffer, and encodes it for uart communication. The output of dataframe is passed to the input of the uart tx function. I developed dataframe as its own mini static library so it can be unit tested, so I defined a callback function as its output interface.

My issue is I am currently hooking dataframe's output to the uart tx handler during runtime through the use of a function pointer, called DF_write_cb as shown below:

```
void main(...){
    DF_set_write_callback(Uart_Tx_String, NULL);
    ...
}

void DF_apply_frame(uint8_t* buff, size_t len)
{
    uint16_t calc_fletcher = fletcher16(buff, len);
    buff[len] =   (calc_fletcher>>0) & 0xFF;
    buff[len+1] = (calc_fletcher>>8) & 0xFF;
    len+=2;
    uint8_t s=DF_START_BYTE; 
    DF_write_cb(&s, 1);
    DF_escape_frame(buff, len);
    s=DF_STOP_BYTE;
    DF_write_cb(&s, 1);
}
```

DF_write_cb points to:

```
bool OPTIMIZE(O3) Uart_Tx_String(uint8_t* string, size_t string_size)
{
    if(string == NULL || string_size <= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this? I have the knowledge of what function I want dataframe to hand off its processed bytes to at compile time, certainly at link time.

Really, I am searching for a way to tell gcc that "DF_write_cb()" is really "Uart_Tx_String()". I'd like to avoid #define if possible. Is there any configuration methods I am unaware of that would let the compiler or linker substitute "DF_write_cb" with "Uart_Tx_String"? I've seen a few references to static inline but I'm unfamiliar how to set this up.

Comment: *`I'd like to avoid #define if possible`* - why? It is the most common and acceptable method to manage compile-time configurations.

Comment: @Eugene It doesnt translate well with a debugging session. Stepping through #defined code doesn't work. This is more of a "is there a better way" question. I can accept the #define solution if I have to, but I thought there was a method using inlines that achieved the same result.